# What is the most efficient way to display a table in Android

Tags: android, json, android-tablelayout

I have a post to server which returns a JSONArray. I then populate a TableLayout by dynamically creating TableRows which get inserted into the TableLayout, and also dynamically create TextViews after which I set the text to values from the JSONArray. And add the TextViews to the Rows.

This does work. Although it seem terribly insufficient and I would really like a more elegant solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, TableLayout is very inefficient, consider you have 100 rows of content, then you have to create 100 rows of widgets.. which is very memory consuming + slow in creation.

Above scenario should be a perfect fit for using ListView, you can simply de-serialize your JSON Array into a custom Adapter to push to the ListView. I usually create/use a JSON-Cursor Adapter so that it can be more reusable (fits to ContentProvider as well).

Comment: Alright I understand the concept of using an ArrayAdapter but it seems it creates a TextView for each Value anyway which sounds like it would be similarly inefficient.

Comment: I am also dynamically adding buttons in the first 'column' with Tags set to ID's which can be clicked to activate an action for that row. I'm not sure if this can still be achieved if using an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Adapter if created correctly, should not makes 1-1 mapping on data-widget. The AdapterViews would help to manage the recycling of view so in ideal case only visible rows + 2 is created.

Comment: Thanks xandy I will give this a shot. Should be able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com is the most efficient way to learn android...

check out this url for your result :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts